# Mutate nested deep object

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I have this object

```
const a = {
  elementErrors: {
    errorMessages: [],
    errors: {
      project: "Issues with this Issue Type must be created in the same project as the parent."
    }
  },
  issueKey: "JP-55",
  status: 400
}
```

and I want to mutate it so that the nested project property includes the issueKey property at the end of the string, something like `"Issues with this Issue Type must be created in the same project as the parent (JP-55)."`

I know I should show that I tried and I did but I haven't managed to come with the beginning of a solution.

The final object would look like this:

```
const a = {
      elementErrors: {
        errorMessages: [],
        errors: {
          project: "Issues with this Issue Type must be created in the same project as the parent (JP-55)."
        }
      },
      issueKey: "JP-55",
      status: 400
    }
```

Many thanks

Comment: Does the `project` always ends in a dot? It's *kinda hard* to insert it at the end without any fixed position.

Comment: it can be placed after the dot. At the end of the string, the issueKey. But it should always end with dot yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `+=` operator to 'add' something to the end of the string.

```
a.elementErrors.errors.project += ` (${a.issueKey})`;
```

```js
let a = {
  elementErrors: {
    errorMessages: [],
    errors: {
      project: "Issues with this Issue Type must be created in the same project as the parent."
    }
  },
  issueKey: "JP-55",
  status: 400
}

a.elementErrors.errors.project += ` (${a.issueKey})`;

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to compute a new property based on some other values. Just try to access and override it.

If you always have a dot at the end, you can use a mix of [`split()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=split%28%29+javascript&sxsrf=ALiCzsZpJKnszN-Augh5BSK0MF6V8Oyr9g%3A1651235605803&ei=FdtrYrnJMPOgseMP4fekgA0&oq=split%28%29+&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYBDIFCAAQkQIyBQgAEJECMgUIABCRAjIFCAAQkQIyBQgAEJECMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6BwgAEEcQsANKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQEVgRYJcLaAFwAXgAgAGCAYgBggGSAQMwLjGYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) and [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
const a = {
  elementErrors: {
    errorMessages: [],
    errors: {
      project: "Issues with this Issue Type must be created in the same project as the parent."
    }
  },
  issueKey: "JP-55",
  status: 400
}

a.elementErrors.errors.project = `${a.elementErrors.errors.project.split('.')[0]} (${a.issueKey}).`;

console.log(a);
```

PS: Above code will break if there is no `.`

Comment: It will also brake if there's another dot inside the project string.

Comment: If there is another `.` it will not work as expected but not break. If there is no dot, the above will outright throw an error. But I wanted to give the OP a solution, with `split()` so he can understand.